# Responsive Web Design: Works in Responsive Mode But Not While Shrinking

Tags: javascript, css, html

First of all, I am not sure whether it's a small ERROR or a strange problem. I am working on a WebPage Design (Front End, No Back End) using HTML5, CSS and some Javascript. 
The problem I am having is with Responsiveness. I am using Mozilla Firefox to test the webpage's Responsiveness (Responsive Mode).

**PROBLEM:** While viewing in Firefox's Responsive Mode, The responsiveness of WebPage Works Just Fine. But, If I try to test it by shrinking the Browser Window, There is no responsiveness at all.

I am unable to figure out what the problem is. And *I am using **CSS Media Queries** For Responsiveness*. 
Some Code Has Been Given Below.
Check Out The **WebPage** Here: http://www.ammini.edu.in/fetera

```css
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   nav .title {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    #del-countdown {
        display: none;
    }
    #boxes {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #boxes .container {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
    }
    #boxes .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 0px;
        /* border-bottom: solid white 2px; */
    }
        #boxes .box h3{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
        #boxes .box p{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
    }
        #patrons {
        background-color: #333333;
        font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    }

    #patrons .container {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #patrons .box {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px 0px;
        color: aliceblue;
    }

    #patrons .box img {
        width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        /* border-radius: 50%; */
    }

    #patrons a {
        font-weight: 550;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: aqua;
    }

    #patrons .box p {
        font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 550;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .logo {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    }
    
    .events {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 768px) {
   nav .title {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    #del-countdown {
        display: none;
    }
    
    #boxes {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #boxes .container {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
    }
    #boxes .box {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px 0px;
        /* border-bottom: solid white 2px; */
    }
        #boxes .box h3{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
        #boxes .box p{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    
    #patrons {
        background-color: #333333;
        font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
    }

    #patrons .container {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #patrons .box {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px 0px;
        color: aliceblue;
    }

    #patrons .box img {
        width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        /* border-radius: 50%; */
    }

    #patrons a {
        font-weight: 550;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: aqua;
    }

    #patrons .box p {
        font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 550;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .events {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr ;
    }

}
```

```html
<section id="patron_div" class="section section-dark">
    <h1 class="title_patron">PATRONS</h1>
    <section id="patrons">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box" id="box1">
          <img src="./img/principal.png">
            <h3>PATRON</h3>
            <p> Dr.Shashi Dharan<br> Principal, Ammini College of Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box2">
          <img src="./img/madhu.png">
          <h3>CHIEF PATRON</h3>
          <p>Mr. K G Madhu<br> Chairman, Ammini College of Engineering</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="box3">
          <img src="./img/hod.png">
          <h3>FEST CO-ORDINATOR</h3>
          <p>Mr. Pradeesh A.R<br> Head of Department, Mechanical Engineering</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </section>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Answer After a long Search.

The problem is I have set the media query to **MAX-DEVICE-WIDTH** rather than targeting the size of window which is **MAX-WIDTH**.